# How to automatically distributes styles from Angular library?

Tags: css, angular, angular-library

I've created a custom angular library and I use it inside another project.
There are multiples components in my library, with some theming styles.
By default, these styles are not applied in the consumer's project. I had to add manually the following line (in angular.json project file) to get library's components styles :

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "./node_modules/@my-lib/components/styles/default-theme.css"
            ]
```

Is there a way to get styles automatically when I add my library in another project (on npm install @my-lib for exemple) ?

From library side, I had also modified ng-package.json

```
"assets": [
    "./styles/**/*.css",
  ]
```

and package.json file :

```
"exports": {
    "./styles/default-theme.css": {
      "style": "./styles/default-theme.css"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Short answer, you can't, user need to add the styles themselves.